# Permission Sets issues

Tags: security

I'm creating new permission sets on my org and I'm having some issues in two cases.

1. I have a related list assigned to Account object. The relation ship between them is via Lookup. I have a permission set with Account CRUD access and Read access for the othe object. However I'm not able to see the related list.
2. I have a VF tab associated to a VF page. I have a permission set that include the vf page. I'm not able to see the tab on my org.

Has anyone know why I'm getting these issues?

Thanks in advance.
Agustina

Comment: I would recommend splitting the parts of your question into two separate posts, Agustina. While they may both be related to permission sets they are two separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second question, be able to add VF tabs related to VF pages to a permission sets. Quite easy to solve.
Go to Permission Sets | App section | Object Settings. There you can find any VF tab apart from the objects.

Comment: Regarding the Related List. It works properly. My issue was that I had 2 different page layouts related to this main object and my Profile had assigned the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding related lists: Permissions to see that are based on the object in the list. Some things to check:

1. Ensure the user otherwise has access to the object in the related list (problems could be sharing rules, access to the proper Record Type, etc. . . )
2. Ensure the related list is actually in the Page Layout for that combination of parent object and user Profile

Comment: Additionally for the tabs i would also check if the tab's visibilty is "Default off" for all/the user's profile who you are logged in as.

Answer (score 1):

Page layouts control the visibility of fields on detail and edit pages, field-level
security controls the visibility of fields in any part of the app, including related lists, list views reports, and search results. In order to be absolutely sure that a user can or cannot access a particular field, it's important to use the field-level security page for a given object to set access restrictions for the field.

You might want to review [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) where all this is explained in detail while creating a recruiting app.